# Newbie try put things in order in blueprints

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have some set of levels. Each level has his own button. Part of the corresponding blueprint:
[image]

`Define_Level` is my event, to choose level, based on the pressed button.

Am I need create, conditionally, 20 this small constructions for 20 levels? It sounds very bad. I thought about taking information about button from Event, but i don't find paths to do this.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Afterword:

I create class child of button. Now I can set `Level_num` directly on my button, It's cool.

Last thing that I cant understand is how I can bind that function to `On_Clicked_Event`.

I tried this, but I need set something to `Bind_Event_To_On_Clicked` input.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a new bp class which is a child of the UMG button class, call it something like <kbd>LevelSelectButton</kbd>.

Give the class a `Name` member variable, <kbd>LevelName</kbd>

Then define a function there called <kbd>SetLevel</kbd> which sets the level using <kbd>LevelName</kbd>. And finally in the button, call <kbd>SetLevel</kbd> using <kbd>LevelName</kbd> on an appropriate event. (I would rather do On Clicked, but if you want it to happen On Released that's up to you).

You will need to create a custom event which makes the call to SetLevel, then use <kbd>Bind Event to On Clicked</kbd> to attach that event. Create another custom event called <kbd>Init</kbd> that calls <kbd>Bind Event</kbd>:

[image: Example of bind event to On Click]

Then in your menu widget(s) which will contain the buttons, you use a <kbd>LevelSelectButton</kbd> for each level select button you want, and assign the <kbd>LevelName</kbd> of each button as the name of the level it should start.

Finally, you will need to call the <kbd>Init</kbd> on each button when the menu is created. One way to do this is to get all the children of the button containers, cast them to <kbd>LevelSelectButton</kbd> then call <kbd>Init</kbd> on them:
[image: example of iterating through children of button containers]

Comment: Yes, I understand your idea. It will be useful both in this situation and in my future work. Thanks for help!

Comment: Hey @ruzihm, can you help me one more time :)

Comment: @Boloto Maybe :) [Ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and we shall see ;)

Comment: @ruzhim I'm edit this question, because I was almost able to realize your idea, but cant do final step

Comment: @Boloto I edited the answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It's great work, @Ruzhim! I didn't quite understand how to create buttons container, but I create an array. This made the blueprint a little more compact, but as i understand container keeps object refernces and it's more optimal than storing buttons directly. 
Can you explain me how to create it?)
Thanks for help again!

Comment: @Boloto I used uniform grid panels, but you might want horizontal box, vertical box, or some combination. Whatever containers you use. You'll need to check the box to make them appear as variables because by default they may not appear as a variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229589/discussion-between-boloto-and-ruzihm).

Comment: You want get all children, not make array